# different response for a same exception using @controlleradvice and @exceptionhandler if exception is generating from different controller

Tags: spring-boot, exception

There are 2 different controllers, one is pickup controller another is delivery controller, I want that whatever is the exception getting generated from either controller for e.g. `IOException`/`BadRequestException`, the`@ControllerAdvice` class should give different response based on the controller class from which exception is getting generated. Like a different response for the same `BadRequestException` for Pickup controller class and a different response for delivery controller class

Comment: Then don't use `@ControllerAdvice`. This is for generic applied logic you want specifics so write a specific `@ExceptionHandler` in those controllers.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum a lot for your comment, just wanted to know if this is not possible because spring doesn't support it or just because its a bad design solution so you are recommending, reason is because i have been given a spike story to do research on this particular thing... so if spring doesn't allow i can stop working on it...

Comment: It would be a bad thing. Why would a generic component need to no a specific controller to do something different. It doesn't belong in that component.

Comment: @M.Deinum, just trying to understand how that is going to be "Controller Aware". If I understand you correctly, are you suggesting adding some sort of param in the Servlet API HTTP request from the Controller that can be interrogated in the @ExceptionHandler? And If yes, is that an acceptable practise

Comment: Why? The `@ExceptionHandler` is part of the specific `@Controller. So why would it be more complex then that. The exception resolving logic will first check the current controller for an exception handler then it will look for more generic components.

Comment: yes trying to add some sort of param ...

Comment: The exception resolving logic will first check the current controller for an exception handler then it will look for more generic components. So why do you need to mess around with parameters/attributes?

Comment: @M.Deinum, Great!. But what if every controller need not have ExceptionHandler and it was just to be implemented as a separate class, is there some preferred way of making it "Controller Aware" ? The only reason I ask is what if we wanted only One ExceptionHandler class rather than a method in every controller?. I guess it is probably a bad practice but would be interested in your view

Comment: You don't want that.  Your controller would suddently know how exceptions are going to be handled technically/internally (because you need to put some state in the request attributes) and your exception handling would suddenlty be aware of the controllers. That is something you want to avoid.

Comment: You can bind an `@ControllerAdvice` to a single controller (check the reference guide) but how would that be different from writing an `@ExceptionHandler` in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarise possible setup's for the case when you have two different controllers throwing same exception and you want to handle that exception in different ways per controller.

**Setup 1:**

Create separate `@ExceptionHandler` methods in each controller. Recommended if you want to handle exception just for this controller and don't have `@ControllerAdvice` setup which would override this exception.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pickup")
public class PickupController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/delivery")
public class DeliveryController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Setup 2:**
Create `@ControllerAdvice` for each controllers. Recommended if you have `@ControllerAdvice` which is handling same exception as your controller (might be in some library which you can't change). In this way you will be able to set `@Order` on your `@ControllerAdvice` and set it as primary.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = PickupController.class)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PickupExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = DeliveryController.class)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DeliveryExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```